# Azure Deny custom Policy, if vm backup not enabled

Tags: azure, backup, policy, azure-policy

I am trying to create a custom azure policy such a way that if anyone create a vm and backup is not enabled, then the deployment should fail. I had tried the below codes, but not working.

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
    "name": "enable backuo for-windows-vm",
    "properties": {
        "displayName": "enable backup for-windows-vm",
        "description": "enable backup for-windows-vm",
        "parameters": {},
        "policyRule": {
            "if": {
                "allOf": [
                    {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/backupProtectionIntent"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.Compute"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/Vaults",
                        "Notequals": "True"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "effect": "deny"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/built-in-policies#backup) / [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/built-in-policies/policyDefinitions/Backup/VirtualMachines_EnableAzureBackup_Audit.json) built-in policy helps to achieve your requirement.

[image]